# Can I use a onkey event to print a value to the console with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to print a value to the console window using the on key event in turtle graphics. I know that you can use events to influence turtle objects within a scene, but ideally, this key press event would solely control the value and not effect any other objects being rendered in the turtle screen.

The aim of this is to be able to increment a value on a key press, and print that value to console.

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

val = 0 

# Ideally this function is called every time the space bar is pressed.
def increment_val(): 
    global val 
    val += 1 
    print(val)

#just a dummy to test if the screen is working 
dummy_turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(increment_val,"space") 

screen.listen()
```

The current output: The screen displays a turtle, and console prints 1 regardless of whether or not the space bar has been pressed, then the turtle window crashes. The expected output would be the screen displaying a black turtle in the middle and, and the console output would be 1,2,3.... every time the space bar is pressed. Any help or suggestions are appreciated and thanks !

Comment: Works for me under Python 3 -- only change I made was to add `screen.mainloop()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you, I just added that, and it works for me now !